# Input siempre me envía null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas amigos, estoy editando un blog con laravel y hay que agregarle etiquetas a los post, en la funcion create me los agrega bien en la tabla y la pivot_table, pero cuando quiero editar esas etiquetas en la funcion edit/update, el input que contiene las etiquetas me devuelve siempre null y no me deja actualizarlas

les dejo mis modelos y mis controladores:

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model
{

  protected $filliable = ['PostTitle', 'post', 'slug'];

  public function categories()
  {
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Categories', 'category_post');
  }

  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->BelongsToMany(Tag::class);
  }

}
```

**Tag.php**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $filliable = ['tag'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function posts()
    {
      return $this->BelongsToMany(Post::class);
    }


}
```

**PostController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $post = new Post;
    $post->user_id = auth::id();
    $post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle;
    $post->post = $request->post;
    $post->slug = $request->slug;
    $post->status = '1';
    $post->save();
    $post->categories()->attach($request->categories);

    $tags = new Tag;
     foreach ($request->tags as $tags) {
       $tag = Tag::create(['tag'=>$tags]);
       if($tag->save()){
         $post->tags()->attach($tag->id);
       }
     }


    return redirect('blog')->with('messageSuccess', '¡Tu entrada se ha creado Exitosamente!');
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle;
    $post->post = $request->post;
    $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);

    $tag = $request->input('tags');
    dd($tag);


    //return redirect('blog')->with('messageEdit','¡Tu entrada ' . $post->slug . ' se edito exitosamente!');

}
```

**Edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.dashboardLayout')
@section('title', 'Asiviajo.com')
@section('body-content')

<section id="create-post">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Editar Entrada {{ $post->id }}</h1>
        <p>Aqui puedes crear tus entradas que seran mostradas en la pagina de blog</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('blog.update', ['id' => $post->id ]) }}" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PostTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulo: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="PostTitle" id="PostTitle"  class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo del post..." value="{{ $post->PostTitle}}">
          </div>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="editForm" value="editForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea name="post" rows="8" id="post" cols="80" class="form-control"> {{ $post->post}}</textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="buttonSubmit">Editar</button>
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('blog.index')}}" role="button">Cancelar</a>

          </div>
{{ csrf_field() }}

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="post-panel">
        </div>
        <div class="post-panel-2">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <th>Estatus: </th>
              <td>Activo</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Fecha de creacion: </th>
              <td>{{ $post->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>

            </tr>

          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="post-panel-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="postTags">Etiquetas: </label>
                <input type="text" name="tags[]" class="form-control" value="<?php foreach($post->tags as $tag){echo $tag->tag;} ?>" placeholder="Etiquetas" id="tagBox2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Categoria: </label>
              <div class="multiselect">

                  @foreach($categories as $category)
                  <label>{{ Form::checkbox('categories[]', $category->id, $post->categories->contains($category->id) ? true : false)}} {{$category->category_name}}</label>
                  @endforeach
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postImage">Imagen Destacada: </label>
    <input type="file" id="postImage" onchange="document.getElementById('imgThumbnail').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);">
    <p class="help-block">Imagen que aparecera al principio del post.</p>
    <div class="imgThumbnail">
      <img id="imgThumbnail" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

@stop
```

Comment: Qué te muestra si realizas `dd($request)`?

Comment: `Tag {#214 ▼
  +timestamps: false
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "tag" => null
  ]
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}`

Comment: Parece que no se están enviando bien los datos. Agrega el código de la vista a la pregunta.

Comment: ya la agregue, para aclarar mi idea, yo quiero que las etiquetas que estén puestas en el post se pueda quitar o agregar nuevas según lo desee el usuario, pero al tratar de enviar el formulario en el update siempre me devuelve null, y me da error el controlador.

Comment: Entiendo, en ese caso si quitas todos los tags tendría sentido que llegue nulo. Si dejas algun tag te sale el mismo error?

Comment: Si me sigue saliendo nulo, de hecho como puedes ver en el input, tengo para que devuelva el valor de los tags ya creados, aun así me devuelve null

Comment: Ya encontré el error, era el plugin de jquery el cual no convertía los valores en array, lo he hecho manual usando vue y me ha servido, gracias por la ayuda.